# I'm having a problem calling a function from a different file

Tags: python, function, file, command, python-import

'''python
from T123_P2_func import add_books
def print_menu(commandmenu:dict)-> list:
menu_options = {
1: 'Command Line L)oad file',
2: 'Command Line A)dd book',
3: 'Command Line R)emove book',
4: 'Command Line F)ind book by title',
5: 'Command Line NC) Number of books in a category',
6: 'Command Line CA) Categories for an author',
7: 'Command Line CB) Categories for a book title',
8:'Command Line G)et book''\n'
'R)ate  A)uthor  P)ubliosher C)ategory',

}

for key in menu_options.keys():
print(key, '-', menu_options[key] )
print_menu(menu_options)

File = None

while True:
userinput = (input('Please enter a Command: '))

```
userinput = userinput.upper()
if userinput == 'L':
    print('Book has been Loaded.')
    file = books_to_list('')
    
elif userinput == 'A':
    print('Book has been Added.')
    
elif userinput == 'R':
    print('Book has been Removed.') 

elif userinput == 'F':
    print('Book has been Found.')         
print(userinput)

word1 = (input('Press Q to Quit: '))
if word1 == 'Q':
    break
```

'''
When I call the function from another file every function in that file runs, please what could be the problem and what do I do if I want to call this function by pressing a Letter ?

Comment: Be aware that importing a module the first time in your program always runs the code in the imported module.

Comment: so what can be done?

Comment: The main body of your module should only *define* functions and classes, but it should not have a single actual call to any function. Those belong in the `if __name__ == "__main__":`, block, as indicated in @ljdyer's answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean that every function from `practicing.py` runs, or that the code in the main part of `practicing.py` runs when you import the module?

If everything in the external module is wrapped inside function definitions, importing the module shouldn't have any effect on what you're doing in the main program.

If you still want code that is in the main part of the external module to be executable by running that file, the thing to do is wrap the main part of the module in a function `def main():` and put the following in the main part of the module (this will not run if the module is imported, only if it is run directly):

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I mean all the functions from the module practicing.py runs

Comment: Ah yes thank you for pointing out - I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: I tried but it didn't work

Comment: I notice you added some code to the question, but it doesn't seem to include the external module `T123_P2_func` that is causing the problem? As others have commented, it's very difficult to diagnose or suggest a solution to your problem without being able to see exactly what you're doing or what unwanted behaviour you're experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see entire of code.

But, I think you have to know how to utilize the argument of the function.

Comment: still the same outcome when i do that, i could post the entire code tho if you would like

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: i have posted the full code